XSLT 3.0 burst-streaming - how to store/get value of another branch
We are using Saxon EE 12.x to transform large (multi-GB) XML files into a much smaller internal XML-structure.  We would like to reduce memory-consumption and burst-streaming on each <Document>-node seems to be a prefect match for our application. It works -  but we struggle with some seemingly simple construct: How to get the information like the <PrintDate> of the <ExportHeader>-Branch and add it to each output <Doc>-element as an attribute in a streaming-mode?
The source XML contains 1000s of <Document>-nodes, each <Document>-node contains 1000s of lines of XML, the <ExportHeader>-node is very small, just contains some Meta-info. A reduced example source-XML looks like this:
<Export>
  <ExportHeader>
    <PrintDate>2024-12-24</PrintDate>
  </ExportHeader>
  <ExportContent>
    <Document>
      <LotsOfXml></LotsOfXml>
    </Document>
    <Document>
      <LotsOfXml></LotsOfXml>
    </Document>
    <Document>
      <LotsOfXml></LotsOfXml>
    </Document>
  </ExportContent>
</Export>

our target XML should look like this:
<Exp>
  <Doc PrintDate="???">
    <LotsOfTransformedXML></LotsOfTransformedXML>
  </Doc>
  <Doc PrintDate="???">
    <LotsOfTransformedXML></LotsOfTransformedXML>
  </Doc>
  <Doc PrintDate="???">
    <LotsOfTransformedXML></LotsOfTransformedXML>
  </Doc>
</Exp>

A very simple XSLT would look like this, but we don't know a way to get the <PrintDate> into the <Doc>-node attribute without breaking streamability... Can an <xsl:accumulator> be used to store/get the value, if yes, how?
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
  version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  <xsl:mode name="insideDoc" streamable="no" on-no-match="shallow-copy "/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Export">
    <xsl:element name="Exp">
      <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="PrintDate">
      <!-- how to keep/store this PrintDate, so we can add it to the Doc elements as an attribute later... -->
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ExportContent">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of(Document)" mode="insideDoc"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Document" mode="insideDoc">
    <xsl:element name="Doc">
      <xsl:attribute name="PrintDate" select="'???'"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="insideDoc"/>      
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="LotsOfXml" mode="insideDoc">
    <xsl:element name="LotsOfTransformedXML">
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>


Note that you should use xsl:element only if you need to compute the element name and/or namespace at run-time, otherwise all those <xsl:element name="Exp"> or <xsl:element name="Doc"> can and should be replaced by literal result elements <Exp>...</Exp> or <Doc>...</Doc>.  Makes your XSLT shorter/more compact and easier to read (well, at least as soon as you are accustomed to literal result elements).

Thanks, will try to convince the team here ;-)  (I was also wondering why they used xsl:element consistently in this project - had never seen it before like this)

Use a capturing accumulator https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/extensions/attributes/capture.html e.g.
<xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="PrintDate"/>

<xsl:accumulator name="PrintDate" as="element(PrintDate)*" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
  <xsl:accumulator-rule saxon:capture="yes" match="ExportHeader/PrintDate"
    phase="end" select="$value, ."/>
</xsl:accumulator>

Declare xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/".
...
<xsl:attribute name="PrintDate" select="accumulator-before('PrintDate')"/>


Thanks a lot, this works. It is even simpler - I have been trying for hours to make accumulators work, but I missed having to declare them with the use-accumulators attribute on the mode...

the capturing accumulator is perfect, it adresses exactly the issue I was having - a short header section before a lot of documents - from the documentation:
If a large document has a short header section containing metadata, you can capture a copy of the header in an accumulator, and the header then becomes available throughout the rest of the document processing using the accumulator-after() function.

For streamed processing, you have to explicitly declare the accumulators your mode should use or can declare #all. But somehow, depending on how you run Saxon, you should have gotten an error or warning that the accumulator was not applicable and you needed to add it in the use-accumulators attribute.

yes, I got the error about use-accumulators, but only after I reduced the problem for this post. It seems I did not get the message in the real project, probably because I currently allow the transformation to be called streamable and non-streamable using the "inital-mode" param (for debugging the streaming mode by comparing output). The "outer"-templates have therefore two modes declared on them.

An alternative that avoids the use of a Saxon extension would be an accumulator with match="ExportHeader/PrintDate/text()" as="xs:string" select="string($value)"/>. Capturing accumulators were invented as a way of capturing values more complex than a simple string.

@MichaelKay, yes, you are right, but as Saxon EE is the only implementation of XSLT 3 with streaming and the poster mentioned using Saxon EE 12 there is no need to avoid the Saxon extension. Seemed better to point to that feature as a general approach to store "header" data than to write a simple working use case that lets the user searching for easy options as soon as there is more complex header data.

yep, for my specific case the saxon;capture  feature is very convenient as the real Header tag contains about 20 data elements. With Martin's solution I can use one simple accumulator and have all these information available while I process the Docs.  With the standard approach I need a separate accumulator with type strng for each value in the Header.

@Reto, also note that a capture attribute is proposed for accumulator rules in XSLT 4.0 as a new, then no longer proprietary feature: https://qt4cg.org/specifications/xslt-40/Overview-diff.html#accumulator-declaration, https://qt4cg.org/specifications/xslt-40/Overview-diff.html#capturing-accumulators
